# there is an error in this android code i.putExtra(data ,1). the data cannot be resolved to the variable

Tags: android

I am new to develop android. .there is an error in my android code

```
 intent i =new intent(mainactivity.this,secondactivity.calss);
 i.putExtra(data ,1).
```

> the error is "data cannot be resolved to a type variable

What can I do?

Comment: do you data in your class?

Comment: What is your `data` variable contains ?

Comment: The first parameter contains the key so need to define the key to access the defined value and it must be in string. So make sure you have defined a key properly. As well as you have written the wrong spelling of `class` in first line make sure to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter contains the key so need to define the key to access the defined value and it must be in string. So make sure you have defined a key properly.

As well as you have written the wrong spelling of `class` in first line make sure to correct that.

Try as below:

> ```
>   Intent i =new Intent(mainactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
>   i.putExtra("data" ,1);
> ```

**public Intent putExtra (String name, int value)**

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

**Parameters**

*name*  The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
*value*  The integer data value.

**Returns**

*Returns* the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.